# How to print Grails params without the flattened keys

Tags: grails, dictionary, flatten

`params` in Grails is a GrailsParameterMap that automatically builds up sub-Maps by splitting parameter names that contain dots.

For example, if my query string is `?one.two.three=hello` then Grails gives me a `params` variable that contain both the flattened (original) and the re-structured values:

```
params == [
    "one.two.three": "hello",
    one: [
        "two.three": "hello",
        two: [
            three: "hello",
        ],
    ],
    // plus "controller parameters"
]
```

If we ignore the additional "controller parameterss", such as `controller` and `action`, how can I get a clean version of this, withouth the original flattened parameters?

```
[
    one: [
        two: [
            three: "hello"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: The params object is a [GrailsParameterMap](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsParameterMap.html) but I don't see any useful methods there. Maybe use `toQueryString` and pull that apart again (kludgy)?

Comment: If nothing else comes up, I'll write a simple recursive function to create a new map with only the keys without a dot.